# Draw charts only for one single value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sparklines

I am using sparkline charts in jquery. This may be a bug or a property but when we pass only one single value to charts
the line does not form. Only after receiving more than 1 values it is formed.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adishri22/9mo0r6u6/).

This is my code

```
var values = [5,7];

// Draw a sparkline for the sparkline line chart element element


    $('#line').sparkline(values, {
        type: "line",
        // Make the tooltip say "NA" for values of -1
        tooltipFormat: "{{y:val}}",
        tooltipValueLookups: {"val": {"-1": "N/A"}}
    });
```

How can I change the code so that on receiving only one value also it should draw a line chart?